# error finding and uploading a file in octave

Tags: octave

I tried converting my .csv file to .dat format and tried to load the file into Octave. It throws an error:

```
unable to find file filename
```

I also tried to load the file in .csv format using the syntax

```
x = csvread(filename)
```

and it throws the error:

```
'filename' undefined near line 1 column 13.
```

I also tried loading the file by opening it on the editor and I tried loading it and now it shows me

```
warning: load: 'filepath' found by searching load path
error: load: unable to determine file format of 'Salary_Data.dat'.
```

How can I load my data?

```
>> load Salary_Data.dat

error: load: unable to find file Salary_Data.dat
>> Salary_Data

error: 'Salary_Data' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> Salary_Data

error: 'Salary_Data' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> Salary_Data

error: 'Salary_Data' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> x = csvread(Salary_Data)
error: 'Salary_Data' undefined near line 1 column 13
>> x = csvread(Salary_Data.csv)
error: 'Salary_Data' undefined near line 1 column 13
>> load Salary_Data.dat

warning: load: 'C:/Users/vaith/Desktop\Salary_Data.dat' found by searching load path
error: load: unable to determine file format of 'Salary_Data.dat'
>> load Salary_Data.csv
warning: load: 'C:/Users/vaith/Desktop\Salary_Data.csv' found by searching load path
error: load: unable to determine file format of 'Salary_Data.csv'
```

Salary_Data.csv

```
YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
2.0,43525.00
2.2,39891.00
2.9,56642.00
3.0,60150.00
3.2,54445.00
3.2,64445.00
3.7,57189.00
3.9,63218.00
4.0,55794.00
4.0,56957.00
4.1,57081.00
4.5,61111.00
4.9,67938.00
5.1,66029.00
5.3,83088.00
5.9,81363.00
6.0,93940.00
6.8,91738.00
7.1,98273.00
7.9,101302.00
8.2,113812.00
8.7,109431.00
9.0,105582.00
9.5,116969.00
9.6,112635.00
10.3,122391.00
10.5,121872.00
```

Comment: Presumably you either didn't define the variable `filename` or it doesn't point to the correct file due to a typo or something.

Comment: What is a '.dat' file? How did you obtain it? What do you mean by 'converting'. Do you mean you just renamed the extension from .csv to .dat? Which directory are you currently in when you try to load that file, according to `pwd`? Why do you need to rename the csv file? Also Salary_Data.csv is not a variable, to read the file via csvread you need to put that name in quotes.

Comment: may be   x = dmlread("Salary_Data.csv",",",1)

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou what I mean by converting the file into .dat is i just renamed it using wordpad . I also tried by putting my file name in quotes .

Comment: if instead of renaming the .csv file on the file browser you actually opened with wordpad and "saved as", then it's likely wordpad has added windows-specific line-endings and other headers which may have made your csv file unrecognizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you've stumbled through a whole pile of issues here.

It would help if you didn't give us error messages without the commands that produced them.

The first message means you were telling Octave to open something called *filename* and it couldn't find anything called *filename*.  Did you define the variable filename? Your second command and the error message suggests you didn't.

Do you know what Octave's working directory is? Is it the same as where the file is located? From the response to your load commands, I'd guess not.  The file is located at `C:/Users/vaith/Desktop`.  Octave's working directory is probably somewhere else.

(Try the `pwd` command and see what it tells you. Use the file browser or the `cd` command to navigate to the same location as the file. `help pwd` and `help cd` commands would also provide useful information.)

The load command, used as a command (`load file.txt`) can take an input that is or isn't defined as a string.  A function format (`load('file.txt')` or `csvread('file.txt')`) must be a string input, hence the quotes around `file.txt`.  So all of your `csvread` input commands thought you were giving it variable names, not filenames.

Last, the fact that `load` couldn't read your data isn't overly surprising.  Octave is trying to guess what kind of file it is and how to load it.  I assume you tried `help load` to see what the different command options are? You can give it different options to help Octave figure it out.  If it actually is a csv file though, and is all numbers not text, then `csvread` might still be your best option if you use it correctly.  `help csvread` would be good information for you.

It looks from your data like you have a header line that is probably confusing the load command. For data that simply formatted, the csvread command can bring in the data.  It will replace your header text with zeros.

So, first, navigate to the location of the file:

```
>> cd C:/Users/vaith/Desktop
```

then open the file:

```
>> mydata = csvread('Salary_Data.csv')
mydata =

       0.00000       0.00000
       1.10000   39343.00000
       1.30000   46205.00000
       1.50000   37731.00000
       2.00000   43525.00000
       ...
```

If you plan to reuse the filename, you can assign it to a variable, then open the file:

```
>> myfile = 'Salary_Data.csv'
myfile = Salary_Data.csv

>> mydata = csvread(myfile)
mydata =

       0.00000       0.00000
       1.10000   39343.00000
       1.30000   46205.00000
       1.50000   37731.00000
       2.00000   43525.00000
       ...
```

Notice how the filename is stored and used as a string with quotation marks, but the variable name is not.  Also, `csvread` converted non-numeric header data to 'zeros'. The help for `csvread` and `dlmread` show you how to change it to something other than zero, or to skip a certain number of rows.  If you want to preserve the text, you'll have to use some other input function.